# Escaping > not working in embedded command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm running this on `Windows 2003`, *(have no other option)*.

Take the below code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('Dir /s /b E:\file 2^>nul') do (
    @echo %%f
)
```

This is recursively searching `E:` for all files named `file`. It then prints out the match, which looks something like `E:\path\to\file`.

So, `Dir` naturally prints `File Not Found` following it's search, this is printed to `stderr`.

So, I try to redirect `stderr` with the below *(which is in the command above)*:

```
2^>nul
```

The `^` escapes the `>` as the `Dir` command is embedded. However, I simply get the error, *(despite this being the common solution by many)*:

```
> was unexpected at this time
```

I've tested this on `Windows 7` and it works fine, so I try enclosing the `>` in speech marks, which was used in `NT` and previously *(to the best of my knowledge)* to escape characters.

```
2">"nul
```

And this behaves the same, still outputting to `stderr`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your command looks like it is doing a recursive listing of the directory `E:\file`, not looking for files with no extension named `file` anywhere within `E:`. If you wanted to do a recursive search in `E:` for any extensionless file named `file` then perhaps the `Where` command could replace your `Dir` command: `@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R E: file') Do @Echo %%A`

Comment: I agree with both of @Mofi's comments.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Mofi. It is though - you take it out and it executes, put it in and it doesn't. I run the same on Window 7 and it works too.

Comment: @Mofi you were right. I was RDP'd into a Win2003 box from my OS X machine. When turning echo off (which I was an idiot for not doing in the first place) I saw a strange char. Used character map to put a real hat in there and award I go...